# Image Cropping from Gallery

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to crop selected image from a gallery (Programmatically). I have done a  lot of research and got the [tutor]**(http://iosdevelopertips.com/graphics/how-to-crop-an-image.html)** gone through this.still getting confuse whether cropping of image can be done by using UIImagePickerController or UIImageView.I'm not getting from where to start or how to start?. please suggest me the right way any one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer :** [**CGImage Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html)

**1) Create a rectangle that represents a cropped image from the middle of the existing image :**

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(size.width / 4, size.height / 4 , 
    (size.width / 2), (size.height / 2));
```

**2) Create bitmap image from original image data, using rectangle to specify desired crop area :**

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

**3) Create and show the new image from bitmap data :**

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
```

### Useful Links :

**1)** [Working with UIGestureRecognizers](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/).

**2)** [Cropping and Resizing Images from Camera in iOS and Objective-C](http://www.samwirch.com/blog/cropping-and-resizing-images-camera-ios-and-objective-c).

GoodLuck !!!